# How do I get the log group associated with a Lambda function in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I see that I can get the log group as an environment variable from within the Lambda itself through the [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) but if I have a Cloudwatch Event of a Lambda success or failure, how can I use the Lambda function name to identify the log group it's writing to? I don't see any lambda or cloudwatch boto3 client methods that provide this functionality.

This provides some details about the Lambda function (including env variables) but doesn't include log group

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')
client.get_function(FunctionName=function_name)
```

There's this on the cloudwatch side, but it requires a prefix to the log group, no way to tie a resource ARN to the log group ARN.

```
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
client.describe_log_groups()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just explored that AWS have recently added the logging config details to get_function response. So now you can get log group name for a lambda like this:

```
def get_log_group(function_arn):
    function_details = boto3.client('lambda').get_function(FunctionName=function_arn)
    return function_details.get('Configuration').get('LoggingConfig').get('LogGroup')
```

it was missing when using `boto3==1.26.161`, but see it started being returned after updating to `boto3==1.29.5`, so make sure to check if you got some recent version if you don't see `LoggingConfig` in the response.

Answer (score 2):

[Original answer prior to November 2023] There is no API or SDK function to retrieve the log group name for a given Lambda function. Instead, you can simply infer it from the Lambda function name, for example:

```
def get_log_group_name(function_name):
    return f"/aws/lambda/{function_name}"
```

If you want to go a step further and ensure that a Lambda function with the given name actually exists, then you can use some variant of:

```
import boto3

def get_log_group_name(function_name):
    lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")

    try:
        response = lambda_client.get_function(FunctionName=function_name)
        if "Configuration" in response:
            log_group_name = f"/aws/lambda/{response["Configuration"]["FunctionName"]}"
            return log_group_name
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Couldn't find the specified Lambda function: {function_name}"
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        raise e
```

As of November 2023, you can now supply a custom log group name when creating a Lambda function (see CloudFormation [LoggingConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-loggingconfig.html)) and also retrieve the log group name from the Lambda function configuration using [get_function_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/get_function_configuration.html).